# Display image based upon the image url in TbDetailView

Tags: php, yii

I have the following code:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
     'data'=>$model,
     'attributes'=>array(
         'logo1',//image url for logo1
         'logo2',//image url for logo2
     ),
));
?>
```

Instead of `logo1,logo2` i want to display the image like `CHtml::tag("img",array("src"=>"/"."$data->logo1")` in TbGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column to use the `html` format with [`CHtml::image`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail) just like in the `CGridView`, the difference being that we use `$data` in `CGridView` but `$model` in  `CDetailView`

```
'attributes'=>array(
     array(
         'attribute' => 'logo1',
         'type' => 'html',
         'value' => CHtml::image('/'.$model->logo1), 
     ),
     ...
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks it was work correctly, and i also want set the image width and height.